# Are the US presidential electors the members of House of Representatives?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, house-of-representatives, electoral-college

My question is about the US presidential election. I read that the Electoral College consists of 435 electors, 100 senators and 3 others. Are the 435 electors the members of the House of Representatives? If No, then what will happen to these 435 electors after they elect the US President?

Comment: Since Congress certifies the ballots of the electors, wouldn't that mean that they're certifying their own actions?

Comment: Remember if you **ever** say "I read that..." I will demand you tell everyone exactly where you read it.

Comment: Article II of the US Constitution explicitly forbids electors being members of Congress: "Each State shall appoint, in such Manner as the Legislature thereof may direct, a Number of Electors, equal to the whole Number of Senators and Representatives to which the State may be entitled in the Congress: but no Senator or Representative, or Person holding an Office of Trust or Profit under the United States, shall be appointed an Elector."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

There is the same number (plus 3 for Washington DC), but they are NOT the members of the House or Senate.

https://www.archives.gov/electoral-college/about

> **How many electors are there? How are they distributed among the States?**
>
> The Electoral College consists of 538 electors. A majority of 270
> electoral votes is required to elect the President. Your State has the
> same number of electors as it does Members in its Congressional
> delegation: one for each Member in the House of Representatives plus
> two Senators. Read more about the allocation of electoral votes.
>
> The District of Columbia is allocated 3 electors and treated like a
> State for purposes of the Electoral College under the 23rd Amendment
> of the Constitution. For this reason, in the following discussion, the
> word “State” also refers to the District of Columbia and “Executive”
> to the State Governors and the Mayor of the District of Columbia.

Answer (score 5):

> Are the US presidential electors the members of House of Representatives?

No.

> I read that the Electoral College consists of 435 electors, 100 senators and 3 others

Either you misunderstood your source or it is incorrect.  The number of electors is equal to the number of representatives plus the number of senators plus 3, with the 3 being the one representative and two senators that would represent the District of Columbia in congress if it were a state.  But no senator or representative may be an elector.

Answer (score 2):

> If No, then what will happen to these 435 electors after they elect
> the US President?

Nothing.

Their job is complete and they cease to be electors after they go to their local statehouse and cast their electoral votes, a few weeks after the last day for voters to cast their voters on the first Tuesday after the first Monday of November in a Presidential election year.